# Why was the courtroom empty during the pre-climax scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

In the middle of the *Molly's Game* (2017) movie, during the courtroom scene, we see
that the courtroom is crowded:

[image]

But in the pre-climax scene, which took place in the courtroom, the judge
determined that Molly had not committed any serious crimes and imposed
a sentence of 200 hours of community service, one year of probation, and
a $200,000 fine. However, the courtroom was eerily empty:

[image]

Why was the courtroom empty during the pre-climax scene?

Comment: People aren't interested in the sentence, they were originally there because, initially, they thought there might be some sensational revelations. That didn't happen so they stopped coming.

Comment: A $200,000 fine doesn't suggest that the court took the sentencing lightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I served on the jury in a criminal embezzlement case in the US (though not in the same state as Molly Bloom's trial) and there were a number of post-verdict motions and continuances (re-schedules) that caused the sentencing to happen more than a year after the end of the trial.  The number of people who attended the sentencing was much smaller than the trial.  Some people lost interest over the months, others stopped coming out of frustration after they traveled to the courthouse several times only to find the hearing had been re-scheduled, and at least one (me) missed the sentencing because they didn't re-check the court calendar in time to attend.  These factors could also have reduced the attendance for Molly Bloom's sentencing.

Comment: ...but Aaron Sorkin could have chosen to show a near-empty courtroom for dramatic purposes rather than as an accurate portrayal of the hearings.  E.g., to contrast the high drama of the trial with the anticlimax of the sentence.